# Is "passed" a valid word for a grade in 4-level grade system?

Tags: grades, netherlands

I have recently had a university diploma translated from Russian to English, and the translator used words Excellent, Good and Passed for 5, 4 and 3 marks correspondingly. However, I could not find usage of such nomenclature on the Internet, it is always mentioned as "Satisfactory".

Will this create problems when I apply to universities? Or is this word also alright to signify lowest passing grade?

(I am mostly planning on applying to universities in Netherlands, but maybe other establishments that teach in English.)

Comment: "Passing" or "passed" as the lowest passing grade will not cause confusion in the US. I feel like that's pretty familiar, if not common, terminology.

Comment: @StellaBiderman - Looks like answer material to me.

Comment: @aparente001 I have no experience with or knowledge of the Netherlands though